# Compare two dates with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I need to compare two dates in a JPQL query but it doesn't work.

Here is my query:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT h 
     FROM PositionHistoric h, 
          SeoDate d 
     WHERE h.primaryKey.siteDb = :site 
     AND h.primaryKey.engineDb = :engine 
     AND h.primaryKey.keywordDb = :keyword 
     AND h.date = d 
     AND d.date <= :date 
     ORDER BY h.date DESC");`
```

My parameter date is a java.util.Date

My query return a objects list but the dates are upper and lower to my parameter.

Someone kown how to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post fragments of your `PositionHistoric` and `SeoDate` classes where relevant properties are annotated? It's pretty hard to understand what's happening otherwise; your naming scheme seems rather  inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

The query you should use is:

```
 FROM PositionHistoric h
   INNER JOIN FETCH h.date
WHERE h.primaryKey.siteDb = :site
  AND h.primaryKey.engineDb = :engine
  AND h.primaryKey.keywordDb = :keyword
  AND h.date.date <= :date
```

Note that ordering by `h.date` is rather pointless (as it points to SeoDate entity and thus in effect you're ordering by PK) and you can't order by `h.date.date` since SeoDate is mapped as `many-to-one`.

Also note that `INNER JOIN FETCH h.date` line is not necessary per se but it will save you some overhead on additional lazy queries IF you will actually need to use SeoDate attributes in the returned list.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I obtain a PositionHistoric but I'm not sure that this object is the last date known

Comment: You obtain a **list** of `PositionHistoric` entities; all of them will be linked to `SeoDate` entities with dates earlier then your parameter. That's what the original query you've posted attempted to do, except it works. If you need to do something else, you need to clarify your question and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I found my error. In my primaryKey, the date wasn't include so JPA return everytime the same object. I had included the date in primaryKey and all work fine.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date

Because you pass it to a JPQL(kind of SQL).

I usually use TIMESTAMP instead of Date, but if you didn't have the choice..

And is it :   h.date = d.date  instead h.date = d  ?